# MVC4 Recently Added

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

I would like to display 5 recently added Anime and Manga on my home page. I have 2 models

```
public partial class ANIME
{    
    public int ID_AN { get; set; }
    public string SMALL_PIC { get; set; }
    public string TITLE_OR { get; set; }
    public string TITLE_EN { get; set; }
}


public partial class MANGA
{    
    public int ID_AN { get; set; }
    public string SMALL_PIC { get; set; }
    public string TITLE_OR { get; set; }
    public string TITLE_EN { get; set; }
}
```

I tried to create 3rd model which contains both of them like this:

```
public partial class Recent
{
    public virtual ICollection<ANIME> Anime { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<MANGA> Manga { get; set; }
}
```

In View I would like to make something like this:

```
@model AnimeWeb.Models.Recent

@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Anime)
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Manga)
```

Of course I would also create proper DisplayTemplates for both of them. The problem is I have no idea what to do in controller. How to populate both Anime and Manga and send them both to view?

Comment: in controller get the data from database. if you are using entity framework then get data from dbcontext and pass data to view it will show.

Comment: What exactly are you using to store information and what are you going to use to retrieve that information?